# Eigenvalue decomposition for a very huge matrix of medical images(such as the pixel physical coordinates of CT images)

Tags: python, matrix, numeric, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am trying to do eigenvalue decomposition for a huge matrix which size is more than 788000 * 788000 for medical image analysis. The matrix is not sparse and every element in the matrix has a real value. And, for example, I want to obtain the first 20 eigenvectors corresponding to the first 20 largest eigenvalues.

1. The computer is not able to do eigenvalue decomposition for the huge matrix and the memory is overflow, although my computer configuration is very excellent.
2. I write the computer codes with Python language and other related packages(such as numpy, opencv, matplotlib and so on)

Is there any other python lib or related package that can do eigenvalue decomposition and solve the computation problem?
or is there any other method that can solve this problem with python?
I am in a difficult situation now, hope someone can help me.
Thank you so much.

**So sorry, I wrote wrongly, the huge matrix is ​​also symmetric.**

Comment: This smells like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2682422/eigenvalue-decomposition-of-huge-matrices)

Comment: There is no such lib. To do that, you'll need a supercomputer as your matrix has asize of at least 6.209.440.000.000.000 bytes

Comment: Also, if your data has spatial information, meaning close data points are very correlated, consider using a convolutional auto-encoder with a bottle neck of size 20, and taking that as the reduced dimension. This is a topic with no bottom, and relies on what you are actually after to offer better solutions.

Comment: The main problem is how to use more clever methods to perform eigenvalue decomposition of large matrices and obtain eigenvalues and eigenvectors. If we decompose the huge matrix directly for eigenvalues and eigenvectors, the computer cannot accomplish this task

Comment: thank you @Gulzar. It seems that there is no clever algorithm for decomposing the huge matrix

Comment: thank you @ Programmer. sounds a bad news....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not too familiar with PCA for image analysis. [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319248454_Principal_component_analysis_to_reduce_dimension_on_digital_image/fulltext/5e6ffc60a6fdccc06e9495fc/Principal-component-analysis-to-reduce-dimension-on-digital-image.pdf?origin=publication_detail) describes a method of PCA on images where for WxH images, you perform PCA column-wise, requiring SVD on only a WxW matrix. This produces a PCA per image, however, so not exactly what you are asking.

Since SVD ([singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)) has a cubic (O(n^3)) time complexity, I doubt it would be practical to crunch the numbers you are proposing on any machine in any language. If you still really want to go your way, you might want to consider reducing the image size first by resizing the image to lower pixel count and running your proposed method on smaller images. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_gallery_of_image_scaling_algorithms) page for different resizing algorithms. Many of them are implemented in the PIL Python image module ([see here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize)).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The paper you provided used PCA (eigenvalue decomposition) to compress an image. But It is not about proposing a new method for huge matrix eigenvalue decomposition. I want to do eigenvalue decomposition for the huge matrix. Thanks very much for your nice advice